# how do I debug this?

Tags: unity-game-engine, tweak

Assets/scripts/JavaScripts/PerformanceTweak.js(218,45): BCE0051: Operator '<' cannot be used with a left hand side of type 'Object' and a right hand side of type 'float'.

```
while( times.length > 0 && times[0] < 0.0 ) {
    times.Shift();
    messages.Shift();   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like `times[0]` returns an object, and 0.0 is a float, and what ever language this is doesn't support comparison between the two, at least not in this form. You need to find a way to cast `times[0]` to float for proper comparison. This may be something like: `(float)times[0]` or `[times[0] floatValue]`. (I don't know the language)

Comment: something like converting the object to float ?

Comment: @ArchieAzares At some point before the comparison, or directly within it.

Comment: I had tried converting it to float but instead of being converted to float it looks to me that it was being converted to int which I can't understand. by the way I'm using assembly platform for this java script.

Comment: by the way. what do you mean by directly within it? I really don't know how I would be able to convert it directly within the while condition? is it possible  to convert it within the condition? thanks ..